# On some conjectures regarding repunits

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, recreational-mathematics, factoring, repunit-numbers

While researching the topic of [Descartes numbers](http://www.uncg.edu/%7Ef_saidak/dn.pdf), I came across the following seemingly related subproblem:

> **PROBLEM:** Determine conditions on $n$ such that
> $$\frac{{10}^n - 1}{9}$$
> is squarefree.

**MY ATTEMPT**

Set
$$m := \frac{{10}^n - 1}{9}.$$

(Note that $m$ is called a [repunit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repunit).  Searching for the keyword "squarefree" in this Wikipedia page did not return any results.)

I noticed that $m$ is squarefree for $n = 1$.

So, let $n > 1$.  I also observed that, for $n \geq 2$, we actually have
$$m \equiv 3 \pmod 4,$$
so that $m$ is **not a square**.

Next, I considered the prime factorizations of $m$ for the first dozen $n \neq 1$:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
\text{Value of } n &\text{Repunit } m & \text{Prime Factorization of } m \\ \hline
2 & 11                   &     11                        \\ \hline     
3 & 111                  &     3 \times 37               \\ \hline 
4 & 1111                 &     11 \times 101             \\ \hline 
5 & 11111                &     41 \times 271             \\ \hline
6 & 111111               &     3 \times 7 \times 11 \times 13 \times 37 \\ \hline
7 &1111111              &     239 \times 4649           \\ \hline
8 & 11111111             &     11 \times 73 \times 101 \times 137 \\ \hline
9 & 111111111            &     3^2 \times 37 \times 333667 \\ \hline
10 & 1111111111           &     11 \times 41 \times 271 \times 9091 \\ \hline
11 & 11111111111          &     21649 \times 513239                  \\ \hline
12 & 111111111111    &     3 \times 7 \times 11 \times 13 \times 37 \times 101 \times 9901 \\ \hline
13 & 1111111111111   &          53 \times 79 \times 265371653 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

From this initial data sample, I predict the truth of the following conjectures:

- **CONJECTURE 1:**  If $n \equiv 0 \pmod 6$, then $m$ is squarefree.
- **CONJECTURE 2:**  If $n \equiv 0 \pmod 6$, then $\bigg(3 \times 7 \times {11} \times {13} \times {37}\bigg) \mid m$.
- **CONJECTURE 3:**  If $n \equiv 0 \pmod 3$, then $\bigg(3 \times {37}\bigg) \mid m$.

I skimmed through [OEIS sequence A002275](http://oeis.org/A002275) and did not find any references to these conjectures.

**RESOLVING CONJECTURE 1**

I searched for counterexamples to **Conjecture 1** using Pari-GP in [Sage Cell Server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLyy_SqLA11FEwNdBRyEzTUNTILC4uLE0sSk0rSk3V0DA0iKtQ0FUw1NS31NRUUFNT0PDNT9Go0DHTVLC1VTDQ1CkoyswrAQqkJSaXAM1C1aCpCQAPqhm6&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==), I got the following output in the range $n \leq 50$:

```
18[3, 2; 7, 1; 11, 1; 13, 1; 19, 1; 37, 1; 52579, 1; 333667, 1]
36[3, 2; 7, 1; 11, 1; 13, 1; 19, 1; 37, 1; 101, 1; 9901, 1; 52579, 1; 333667, 1; 999999000001, 1]
42[3, 1; 7, 2; 11, 1; 13, 1; 37, 1; 43, 1; 127, 1; 239, 1; 1933, 1; 2689, 1; 4649, 1; 459691, 1; 909091, 1; 10838689, 1]
```

This output means that

- $\dfrac{{10}^{18} - 1}{9}$ is divisible by $3^2$.
- $\dfrac{{10}^{36} - 1}{9}$ is divisible by $3^2$.
- $\dfrac{{10}^{42} - 1}{9}$ is divisible by $7^2$.

I therefore conclude that **Conjecture 1** is *false*.

**MY ATTEMPT TO RESOLVE CONJECTURE 2**

I searched for counterexamples to **Conjecture 2** using Pari-GP in [Sage Cell Server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLyy_SqLA11FEwNAABHYXMNA1FDd_8FA0NDUODuAoFXQVDTX1LTR1DMNBUsLVVMNBUUFNTACuq0DGDCukUFGXmlQAF0hKTS4CGougGAgAimBkU&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==), I got a blank output in the range $n \leq {10}^5$.

The Pari-GP interpreter of Sage Cell Server crashes as soon as a search limit of ${10}^6$ is specified.

This gives further computational evidence for **Conjecture 2**.

**MY ATTEMPT TO RESOLVE CONJECTURE 3**

I searched for counterexamples to **Conjecture 3** using Pari-GP in [Sage Cell Server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLyy_SqLA11FEwNAABHYXMNA1FDd_8FA0NDUODuAoFXQVDTX1LTR1DQ0NNBVtbBQNNBTU1BbCKCh1jqJBOQVFmXglQIC0xuQRoIopWIAAA4P4Yfg==&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==), I got a blank output in the range $n \leq {10}^5$.

The Pari-GP interpreter of Sage Cell Server crashes as soon as a search limit of ${10}^6$ is specified.

This gives further computational evidence for **Conjecture 3**.

---

**Alas, this where I get stuck, as I do not currently know how to prove Conjectures 2 and 3.**

**INQUIRY**

> Given that **Conjecture 1** is false, do you know of or can you prove a(n) (unconditional) congruence condition on $n$ which guarantees that the repunit $m$ is squarefree?

Comment: (+1) Very good experimental maths protocol. Thanks

Comment: Determining whether a number is squarefree is believed to be as difficult as factoring. So, in most cases, we can only show that a given repunit is not squarefree, but probably not that it is squarefree. With a little trick , we can however determine for large $n$ and $p$ , whether we have $p^2\mid R_n$. Note that for every prime $p>5$ , there are infinite many $n$ with $p^2\mid R_n$

Comment: I searched for the keyword "repunit" in that Wikipedia page, @miracle173, and it returned an empty result.

Comment: Would you mind fleshing out your last comment as an actual answer, @Peter, so that I can upvote it?  Thanks!

Comment: @ArnieBebita-Dris If $n>3$ is prime, then the prime factors must have the form $kn+1$ increasing the chance that $R_n$ is squarefree. Whether this is always the case is another interesting question.

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @Peter!  I will take it from here.

Comment: @ArnieBebita-Dris I misread this part of your post.

Answer (score 3):

If $p$ is a prime coprime to $10$ , we have $$10^{p(p-1)} \equiv 1\mod p^2$$ because of Euler's theorem and therefore $$10^{kp(p-1)} \equiv 1\mod p^2$$ for every positive integer $k$

Hence , for every prime $p>5$, there are infinite many $n$ such that $p^2\mid R_n$

Whether $p^2\mid R_n$ holds for $p>5$ can be checked in PARI/GP with

```
lift(Mod(10,p^2)^n-1)==0
```

Answer (score 2):

Conjecture 2 is easy to verify using the fact that $u-1$ is a factor of $u^k-1$, so that $x^6-1$ divides $x^{6k}-1$, so that $10^6-1=3^3\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13\cdot37$ divides $10^n-1$ when $6$ divides $n$. Conjecture 3 is similar with the $6$s replaced by $3$s.

For similar reasons, Conjecture 1 is false: if any $\frac{10^m-1}9$ is ever nonsquarefree, then its multiple $\frac{10^{6m}-1}9$ will also be nonsquarefree. The first counterexamples are $\frac{10^{18}-1}9$ and $\frac{10^{36}-1}9$ (both of which are divisible by $3^2$) and $\frac{10^{42}-1}9$ (divisible by $7^2$).

Comment: Splendid and elegant!  I honestly did not see that coming, @GregMartin!  That being said, thank you for your time and attention.

Answer (score 2):

Conjectures 2 and 3 are rather simple to prove. More generally the following holds
$$m(n)|m(kn)\tag 1$$

To get $m(n)$ you simply append a $1$ on the digit string of $m(n−1)$, so
$$m(n)=10m(n−1)+1$$

Note that $$m(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}10^{i}$$

so we have

$$m(kn)=\sum_{i=0}^{kn-1}10^i
=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\sum_{i=jn}^{n(j+1)-1}10^i
=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}10^{jn+i}=\sum_{j=0}^{k}10^{jn}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}10^{i}=m(n)\sum_{j=0}^{k}10^{jn}$$
which proves $(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

[Lengths of nonsquarefree repunits](https://oeis.org/A046412) suggest that $$\dfrac{10^{9k}-1}{9},\dfrac{10^{22k}-1}{9},\dfrac{10^{42k}-1}{9},\dfrac{10^{78k}-1}{9},\dfrac{10^{111k}-1}{9},\dfrac{10^{205k}-1}{9},\dfrac{10^{272k}-1}{9}$$ are not squarefree where $k$ is a positive integer.

---

$\dfrac{10^{9k}-1}{9},\dfrac{10^{22k}-1}{9},\dfrac{10^{42k}-1}{9},\dfrac{10^{78k}-1}{9}$ are not squarefree since
$$3^4\mid 10^9-1,\quad 11^2\mid 10^{22}-1,\quad 7^2\mid 10^{42}-1,\quad 13^2\mid 10^{78}-1$$
hold.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @Arnie Bebita-Dris : I don't know. Maybe because my answer does not try to prove your conjectures. I know that proving your conjectures helps you, but I tried to answer your inquiry because that is what was asked.